# Angularjs automatic refresh for data while using routeProvider

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

I am trying to update the data on a table over an interval of time.The code has got a routeProvider with an URL and controller like shown below. I am using `init()` to get the data in controller. If i use `init()` method inside $interval(), the table is updated with previous values. I mean if there are no new values and 10 records are there it becomes 20 records. How to update with new values alone.

Minimal app.js code

```
    App.controller('PlantCtrl', [ '$scope', 'PlantDetails', '$interval'
, function($scope, PlantDetails,  $interval,) {

$scope.availablePlantDetailsTemp = [];
    $scope.availablePlantDetails = [];

init();  

    function init() {
        $scope.availablePlantDetailsTemp = PlantDetails.resource2.query(function(response) {
        angular.forEach(response, function(item) {
            if (item) {
                $scope.availablePlantDetails.push(item);
            }
        });
        });
            }
$interval(function() {
                init();
                }, 5000);
}  ]);
```

Or if i use resolve inside routeProvider to do the query how can i call the method inside $interval()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You jsut need to clear array before adding new value to it. Array `push` methods add new values to array hence you are facing the issue.

```
function init() {
        $scope.availablePlantDetails = [];
        $scope.availablePlantDetailsTemp = PlantDetails.resource2.query(function(response) {
        angular.forEach(response, function(item) {
            if (item) {
                $scope.availablePlantDetails.push(item);
            }
        });
        });

$interval(function(){
 Init()
},1*2000)
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Could you also please tell me how to do it with resolve. I will update my resolve code also.

Comment: I have already added answer for that. See the second line of my answer

Comment: Yeah that is fine. I saw that. I want to know how to call the query from controller inside $interval()

Comment: Just call the init method from interval. Updated my answer. Check it

Comment: I asked if i use resolve inside routeProvider to do the query like i have soon above, how can i call that from $interval without using init method

Comment: You can't call resolve  inside routeprovider from controller.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for all the inputs.